# How to create object based on interface TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following interface in TypeScript:

```
export interface Defined {
   4475355962119: number[];
   4475355962674: number[];
}
```

I need to create object based on this interface `Defined`:

```
let defined = new Defined();
defined['4475355962119'] = [1];
defined['4475355962674'] = [2];
```

But it does not work for me!

Or may be it should be something as:

```
 export interface Defined {
      array(number): number[];
}
```

I have this JSON object based that I need to create JS objects:

```
  "parameters": {
    "defined": {
      4475355962119: [
      9547,
      9871
      ],
      4475355962674: [
      9829
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start off with a valid JSON string:

```
const data = `{
    "parameters": {
    "defined": {
      "4475355962119": [9547,9871],
      "4475355962674": [9829]
    }
  }
}`;
```

## Interface

If we want to represent this as an interface, the thought process is to keep all the keys, and replace any values with their respective types, like this:

```
interface Data {
    parameters: {
        defined: {
            [index: number]: number[];
        }
    }
}
```

We can then deserialize the data into that type:

```
const result = <Data>JSON.parse(data);
```

And obtain just the "defined" bit:

```
const defined = result.parameters.defined;
```

## Complete Example

Here is a complete example:

```
const data = `{
    "parameters": {
    "defined": {
      "4475355962119": [9547,9871],
      "4475355962674": [9829]
    }
  }
}`;

interface Data {
    parameters: {
        defined: {
            [index: number]: number[];
        }
    }
}

const result = <Data>JSON.parse(data);

alert(result.parameters.defined['4475355962674'][0]); // 9829
```

## Creating Data

If you aren't deserializing the data, you can create it yourself. The type annotation will help you create a correct object.

```
const example: Data = {
    parameters: {
        defined: {
            '4475355962674': [0, 2, 3]
        }
    }
};

example.parameters.defined['4475355962674'][3] = 4;
```

Comment: How to fill `result.parameters.defined`? I mean to create new key and add values as value (array)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet.

```
export interface Defined {
   4475355962119: number[];
   4475355962674: number[];
}
```

---

```
let defined = {} as  Defined;
defined['4475355962119'] = [1];
defined['4475355962674'] = [2];
```

Comment: But when `defined` can contains some others `key (number) : []`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular object literal:

```
let defined = {
    4475355962119 : [1],
    4475355962674 : [2]
};
```